# Связка text.get и re.findall не работает в Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Создаю окно в tkinter окно с 2 текстовыми полями.
При вводе значения в первое поле, код должен искать это значение в excel-файле.

Значение  получаю методом .get на 27 строке и просматриваю excel-документ построчно методом re.findall.

И тут какие то чудеса, если искомое значение прописывать в коде - все работает (переменная search_text).

Но если получать значение через текстовое поле - ни в какую (чтобы проверить достаточно разкоментировать строку 23).

Вот код:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from tkinter import *
import re



path_to_file = 'Штрихкоды.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path_to_file)  # Грузим наш прайс-лист
sheets_list = wb.sheetnames  # Получаем список всех листов в файле
sheets_count = len(wb.sheetnames) #Количество листов



search_text = 4606373148019
search_text1 = "0"
active_sheets_count = 0 
count = 0
 
 
def b1(event):
    global search_text
    #search_text = str (editor.get(0.0, 13.0))
    
    
    text.insert('end', '{}\n'.format('Штрихкод - ' + str(search_text)))
    global count
    count = 0
    active_sheets_count = 0 
    while active_sheets_count < sheets_count:
        sheet_active = wb[sheets_list[active_sheets_count]]  # Начинаем работать с самым первым
        active_sheets_count = active_sheets_count + 1
        row_max = sheet_active.max_row  # Получаем количество столбцов
        column_max = sheet_active.max_column  # Получаем количество строк

        row_min = 1 #Переменная, отвечающая за номер строки
        column_min = 1 #Переменная, отвечающая за номер столбца
                
                
        while column_min <= column_max:
            row_min_min = row_min
            row_max_max = row_max
            while row_min_min <= row_max_max:
                row_min_min = str(row_min_min)

                word_column = get_column_letter(column_min)
                word_column = str(word_column)
                word_cell = word_column + row_min_min

                data_from_cell = sheet_active[word_cell].value
                data_from_cell = str(data_from_cell)
                #print(data_from_cell)
                
                regular = str(search_text)
                result = re.findall(regular, data_from_cell)
                
                if len(result) > 0:
                    #print('Нашли в ячейке:', word_cell)
                    word_cell1 = "D" + row_min_min
                    global search_text1
                    search_text1 = sheet_active[word_cell1].value
                    text.insert('end', '{}\n'.format('Артикул - ' + search_text1))
                    #print('Артикул:', search_text1)
                    text.insert('end', '{}\n'.format('Наименование: ' + sheet_active["E" + row_min_min].value))
                    text.insert('end', '{}\n'.format(''))
                    #print('Наименование:', ' - ', sheet_active["E" + row_min_min].value)
                    #print('Лист:', sheet_active.title)
                        
                row_min_min = int(row_min_min)
                row_min_min = row_min_min + 1
            column_min = column_min + 1

    

 
 

 
 
root = Tk()
root.minsize(width=500, height=400)
root.title("Scan")
editor = Text(height=1)
editor.pack()
text = Text(height=30, bg="darkgreen", fg='white', wrap=WORD)
text.pack()

root.bind('<Return>', b1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824163/how-to-get-the-input-from-the-tkinter-text-widget

Comment: А вы пробовали печатать в консоль или логировать в файл что получается в `search_text` у вас когда берёте значение из текстового поля? Это нужно первым делом проверять.

Comment: @Сергей Кох большое спасибо, мне невдомек было, что текстовый виджет добавляет строки.
Такой код решил проблему search_text = str (editor.get("1.0","end-2c"))

Comment: @CrazyElf 
Да через консоль все работает, проблема была в считывании с графического интерфейса

Comment: Так я и говорил про логирование значения `search_text` после считывания информации из виджета. Сразу бы стало понятно, где проблема.